# Splicing or not on the 12v side of a halogen lighting system

Tags: electrical, halogen

I've concluded that the WH1601-E6A transformer in a light fixture has expired, and ordered a replacement. The 12v wires coming out of the transformer are wired as follows: there a crimp-ons on the ends of the 12V wires, and these slide into spaces where a hex-keyed screw clamps down on them. I'm assuming I should repeat thjs by finding some corresponding crimp fittings; the alternative would be to cut and splice the existing wires to the wires coming out of the old transformer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find a good assortment of the crimp on terminals at any hardware or auto parts store. From your description it sounds like your terminal looks like this:

[image]

If you do not have the appropriate tool to crimp the terminals onto the wire you can purchase one at the same location that you get the terminals. A low cost crimp tool will likely look very similar to:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, it's not a spade lug at all. it's just metal wrapped around the wire.

Comment: Oh OK. Then it must be a sleeve that crimps on around stranded wire so that when it goes into the screw clamp that it acts more like a solid wire and does not fray out.

Comment: I think it is always neater and possibly more reliable to make up the new ends on the wire rather than splice the old wires. However for low voltage application a good soldered butt splice that is then covered over with heat shrink tubing can make the next neatest solution. (Remember to slide the heat shrink tubing up on the wire before soldering if it is too small to slide over the terminals). :^)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is. I will endeavour to repro.